# Passing a variable with escaping double quotes over ssh

Tags: unix, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

If I use a variable with escaping double quotes, ", they get removed over ssh.

Here's an example:

```
$ foo=\"word\"
$ echo $foo
"word"
$ ssh pi@$pi03 "echo $foo"
word
```

Does anyone know why that might be/what the solution could be? I could post the code to the practical use I need the quotes for, but figured this was a simpler way of explaining.

Comment: Please post your C code (if the C tag is relevant). Post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, the C wasn't relevant. But I did solve the problem thanks to @nsilent22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use triple escaping:

```
foo=\\\"word\\"
echo $foo
\"word\"
ssh pi@1pi "echo $foo"
"word"
```

But in general passing variables this way is something you should avoid.